# Getting "No handler for type [{default=Point, es_type=nested, type=string}] declared on field [loc2]"}" , on mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am using mongoostastic package in node js.

My Schema is :

```
    homeTownAddress:
          {
            address: {type:String,default:""},
            loc2: {
                type: { type: String, default: "Point",es_type:"nested"},
                coordinates: {
                    type: [Number, Number],
                    default: [0, 0],
                    index: '2dsphere',
                    es_type: 'geo_point'
                }

            }

        }
```

Any help on this , will be great help for me.

Comment: Did you read in doc https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/blob/master/docs/README.md#geo-mapping and `Notice that the name of the field containing the ES geo data must start by 'geo_' to be recognize as such.`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I try with prefix geo_ but still , it  is showing same issue. One thing , I noticed that  when I add "loc2" object outside the "homeTownAddress" . It is working perfectly.